# Can a chain of simulacra casting a spell make it permanent?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, simulacrum, permanency

This is a weird question.
It has been established that a caster could cast *Simulacrum* on themselves to make a simulacra, then the simulacra can cast *Simulacrum* on the caster to make a second simulacra of the caster, and son on.  Let's call this *a chain of simulacra*.

Certain spells can be made permanent by casting them on the same place daily or weekly for a set period of time, such as a month or year. These spells include *Mordenkainen's Private sanctum*, *druid grove*, *forbiddance*, *guards and wards*, *temple of the gods* and *mighty fortress*.

I am not certain of the wording on these, but could a chain of simulacra make any of these permanent?

Comment: Are you making the assumption that the caster has the means to cast those other spells that are not in their class (such as via magical secrets from a bard ...)

Comment: Is the idea here that the various *simulacra* each count as the same caster, so no one of them has to keep coming back to the same place daily or weekly? If so, that should be clarified in the question...

Comment: I am assuming the caster uses Wish to cast spell that are not in their class. The simulacrum loop can be handled with the 12 hour casting of simulacrum via a 7th level slot, and a wish from a 9th level slot as wish requires only an action, and can recreate the effects of any spell 8th level or lower (I have yet to see a restriction on class).

Answer (score 7):

#### Doing the same thing in the same place for a year already requires a conversation with your DM, so ask them.

Let's be real: most gameplay doesn't happen on the timescale where we're talking about casting these spells consistently for a whole year. *This is something we talk about doing and handwave, rather than actually doing in play.* So we're already going to be talking to the DM about getting our permanent Temple of the Gods established, and it's probably going to be between adventures.

It is unclear from the various spell descriptions if it has to be the *same* caster casting the spell over the course of the year, so that's up to the DM. This whole thing is up to the DM since doing the usual way is mostly going to be working with your DM to begin with.

(You should also talk to your DM about making an army of simulacra *before* you try to pull that in play.)

Answer (score -2):

### Yes, this works, probably.

Let's use *Teleportation Circle* as the example spell to be made permanent.

The relevant text of *Teleportation Circle* says:

> You can create a permanent teleportation circle by casting this spell in the same location every day for one year. You need not use the circle to teleport when you cast the spell in this way.

The biggest restriction is that the spell must be cast in the same place every day for a year, which means that you can't skip a day or you have to start the process over.

In theory, a Wizard with enough levels to *Simulacrum/Wish* loop could order his first simulacra to oversee the project while he's out on adventures, or working in his lab, and the first simulacra would then be more than capable of overseeing the project and instructing further created simulacra when and where to cast their instance of *Teleportation Circle*

The only possible sticking point is this bit:

> **You** can create a [...]

Depending on DM interpretation of this, multiple different creatures casting the spell may not work, so you and your bard pal who take turns every other day to cast the spell may not work. Further, your simulacra *may or may not* count as *"you"*, and it's up to your DM if that works. Although the Adventurers League FAQ on *Simulacrum + Wish* indicates that it's not unreasonable to have the original and the simulacra count as a single entity.

The FAQ:

> **You Are You; and So Is He.** If a *simulacrum* you have created casts *wish*, both you and your *simulacrum* suffer the stress associated with casting the spell—including the risk of being forever unable to cast *wish* again. The inability to cast *wish* extends to any *simulacrum* you create in the future.

Giving the Simulacra a *Spell Gem* that can contain spells of at least level 5 (a very rare item) will allow you to bypass this problem.

Comment: I like the response, but I think there is a work around on this which requires a spell gem of sufficiently high level. When a simulacrum/wish loop were used, you could have the overseer cast the spell daily from a spell gem. The subordinate simulacrum then attune to the empty spell gem and recast the spell into it.  This allows the overseer to recast the spell over and over again from the spell gem.

Comment: @KennethVanBooven Yes, that would actually side-step the problem nicely. It would make the process take a few hours longer per day, since you have to hand it to a simulacra to attune, then they cast the spell, then the overseer has to re-attune, but that's mostly immaterial in a year-long project.

Comment: Actually the overseer wouldn't have to re-attune. The spell gem allows you to to cast the spell from the gem if you know the spell, or it is one your class can cast. You don't need material components or to attune to the gem to cast the spell (attunement is optional). You only have to attune to a spell gem to put a spell into it.